# x64 asm Hooking winsocket2 Connect()

Tags: assembly, proxy, 64-bit, hook

I have made a basic C# tool that opens a bind shell to my Server.
Lets say the IP is 192.168.0.101 and the Port 9500.

My goal is to route traffic from the C# tool to my second Server, lets say it is at 192.168.0.102 and uses the same port.

In order to get what i want i tried to hook the ws2_32.dll function "WSAConnect".
Added a debugger to the C#, placed a breakpoint on function and after all I found out that RDX holds the "sockaddr" which points to what i want to modify.

The first 2 byte are 0x02 0x00 which stands for ipv4 usage.
The second 2 are my Port in hex, and the next 4 was my IP in hex.
From there I modified those bytes to get what I want and made the program continue.

To check if it worked I used "Source Control" from "Task Mannager" and took a look at my C# app. From there I saw a TCP connection that didn't go to my first server but my second server, which was exactly what I wanted.

But after taking a look on both servers, I saw no incoming connections.
After a while the connection in "Source Control" was gone, there where also no packets send meanwhile.

How does it come my connection didn't start? Have I overlooked something?

Comment: in your case you need to try to use import address table hooking

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, I have finally found the answer.
It turns out that everything was correct, but I had to simply wait before sending my first packet.
The connection was not yet created by the kernel, resulting in failure for the `send()`.
To fix this I ended up doing a `Send()`, check `WSAGetLastError()`, and repeated until it succeded. to prevent getting stuck in an inf-loop I added a counter that times out after a few tries.